# Spotfire - Custom sub total

Tags: spotfire

I would like to calculate sub total in Spotfire cross table based on a condition and color the sub total row.

As shown in the table below, I would like to add sub total of all the rows by store except 'Watermelon' but show 'Watermelon' sales row in the table. Please let me know if this is possible.

Example below:

**Cross Table:**
[image: subtotal]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find an alternative to the answer below? Any comments?

Comment: @scsimon- Thanks for the follow-up. I didn't find an alternative solution yet but have an idea in mind. I will post my comments as soon as I test the solution.

Comment: I'm looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is No.

Sub Total and Grand Total is calculated based off the data in the visualization, regardless if you are rendering it or not so it's not "adjustable" without removing / limiting the data via custom expression or filters. The only real way around this would to create a Store named "Sub Total" which contained all of the data for all fruits excluding watermelon. It's not really recommended though.

Here was a similar post on this issue....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38852432/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177511/6167855