# Grand Total Issue in Cross Table of Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

When I use `FIRST(CG1)` in 'Cell Values' the grand total is not summing up instead its showing one of the values from the result of `FIRST(CG1)`.

Please advise if we have to always use `sum(XXX)` to get the grand total summed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes if you want the `Grand Total` to be a summation of your data. Applying a grand total to a different aggregation will have different results.

- `AVG` will average the averages of your `Category Axis`
- `MAX` will take the `MAX` of the `Max` for each category
- `Cumulative Sum` will take the "Last" value in your `Category` since it doesn't have any additional values to `SUM` up.
- `Product` will take the `Product of Products`
- `First` and `Last` you are already aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Long Answer:

You actually CAN sum the first value of a column from a column grouping.

For example, consider the following data set.

[Grouping]  [Food]  [Color] [Weight] 
Fruit  Apple  Yellow 4
Fruit  Apple  Green 2
Fruit Apple Red 4
Fruit  Banana Yellow 5
Fruit Banana Brown 2
Fruit  Orange Orange 3 
Vegetable Carrot Orange 4

If, in your custom expression, you put

```
Sum(if(RankReal([Grouping], "ties.method=first", [Food]) = 1, [Weight], 0))
```

it will find the first instance of each food in your data set, so regardless of how you group the left, your results, subtotals, and grand totals will sum only the first instance of each food.

So you will be able to see the following:

Fruit     Apple        4
            Banana     5
            Orange     3
            Subtotal:  12
Vegetable Carrot  4
            Subtotal:   4
Grand Total:        16

Answer (score 0):

The ability to use sum in the totals was added at some point. On the properties Totals tab you can select 'As the sum of cell values'. See attached image.

[image]